# Etsy StaggeredGridView Loading Indicator

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I'm using the Etsy StaggeredGridView:

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

and I've connected it to and EndlessAdapter implementation using the cwac-endless library to allow for endless scrolling:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

The issue I'm having is that the loading indicator from the EndlessAdapter appears as a grid item instead of appearing below the grid across the full width.  I'm using a 3 column grid so sometimes the loading indicator is on the left, sometimes on the right, and then sometimes in the middle (depending on how many items have been loaded at that moment).

Can anyone tell me how a full-width loading indicator is intended to be implemented with the **Etsy StaggeredGridView**?  And bonus points if you can tell me how to adjust the EndlessAdapter implementation to work with the StaggeredGridView in terms of the loading indicator.